# Manipulating pixels in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, image-processing, canvas

I'm trying to write simple 2D top-down game with grid based map and I have problem with manipulating pixels in certain canvas area. I have following function:

```
changeCellBackground(x, y, r, g, b){

    let cell = this.context.getImageData(x * this.TILE_SIZE, y * this.TILE_SIZE, this.TILE_SIZE, this.TILE_SIZE);

    for(let i=0; i<cell.data.length; i+=4){

        cell.data[i] += r;
        cell.data[i+1] += g;
        cell.data[i+2] += b;
    }

    this.context.putImageData(cell, x * this.TILE_SIZE, y * this.TILE_SIZE);
}
```

where context is canvas 2d context:

```
this.screen = $('#game');
this.context = this.screen[0].getContext('2d');
```

and Img tag which has src link to tileset:

```
let tileSet = $('<img></img>').attr('src', '../assets/tiles.png');
```

However when I try to use above function, I'm getting `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.`. As I understand it happens because of CORS limitations, so I try to `add crossOrigin="anonymous"` attribute to `Img`:

```
let tileSet = $('<img></img>').attr('crossOrigin', 'anonymous').attr('src', '../assets/tiles.png');
```

But now I'm getting `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE:`. I guess it happens because image hasn't loaded yet when rest of script started to execute. How do I fix this? I tried this:

```
let tileSet = $('<img></img>');

    tileSet.onload = function(){

        tileSet.attr('crossOrigin', 'anonymous').attr('src', '../assets/tiles.png');

        gameScreen.drawAnimatedImage(0, 0, 'waterfall');
        gameScreen.drawAnimatedImage(2, 2, 'fountain');
        gameScreen.drawAnimatedImage(11, 5, 'street_lamp');
        gameScreen.drawAnimatedImage(10, 5, 'street_lamp');
        gameScreen.changeCellBackground(10, 15, -30, -30, -30);
    };
```

But it isn't working either - when I set `console.log(tileSet)` at the end of `onload` function nothing is logged on console. It seems that onload function didn't triggered. Why is that happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: You are setting the `src` attribute **inside** your load event handler, which needs the `src` to be set for firing some day...  Put this line out of this handler. IMO this question should be closed as typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is a much easier way to add a value to the pixels on the canvas.

Your function

```
changeCellBackground(x, y, r, g, b){
```

Adds r,g,b to each pixel on the tile at x,y

can be done with

```
function changeCellBackground(x, y, r, g, b){
     this.context.fillStyle = "rgb(" + Math.floor(r) + ","  + Math.floor(g) + "," + Math.floor(b) + ")";
     this.context.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter"; // adds the fill color to existing pixels
     this.context.fillRect(x * this.TILE_SIZE, y * this.TILE_SIZE, this.TILE_SIZE, this.TILE_SIZE);
     this.context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; // restore default composite operation
 }
```

The above function is identical to your function but without the need to access the pixel data. This means you don't have to worry about the insecure image and can load it without the cross origin header.

As a guess, if you are working off your hard drive (ie `../assets/tiles.png` is on your hard drive) you are not going to get a CORS image as that requires a server.

You can set up a server on your computer (there are many options) and then use the domain localhost in which case the image is not cross domain and does not need the headers. Or you can look up the browser security switches and turn off cross origin security which will give you access to the image data as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's no link between `changeCellBackground()` and the `tileset` in your question, so I'm not sure if there's more problem ahead, but to wait for the image to load, you actually need to put the src part out of the function:

```
let tileSet = $('<img></img>');

tileSet.onload = function(){
    gameScreen.drawAnimatedImage(0, 0, 'waterfall');
    gameScreen.drawAnimatedImage(2, 2, 'fountain');
    gameScreen.drawAnimatedImage(11, 5, 'street_lamp');
    gameScreen.drawAnimatedImage(10, 5, 'street_lamp');
    gameScreen.changeCellBackground(10, 15, -30, -30, -30);
};

tileSet.attr('crossOrigin', 'anonymous').attr('src', '../assets/tiles.png');
```

As it stands currently the onload event is not triggered because there was no src to load from.